# Does A20 line only disable 20th it or all bits from 20th and above?

Tags: memory, x86

According to this picture:

[image]

Only the 20th bit is disabled until we enable it with keyboard controller (or BIOS). Based on the diagram, I think that the wrap around feature is retained for old programs by always set A20 to 0, effectively prevent carry bit from bit 19th and achieve a wrap around after a calculation. However, when we set bits 21th and above, those bits can still be used as normal for calculation, since they are not masked out.

But some resources state that A20 line disables 20th and above bits. Which is correct?:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only the A20 line; the origin of this hack was a bug in the 80286 processors that failed to set that line to 0 in real mode.

It also failed to set the others, but real mode programs did not care, so only that line got the gate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, why do other bits above 20th are not usable as well until we set bit 20th?

Comment: @TuDo: They are, just due to bit 20 being set to 0 when the gate A20 is not active, the physical memory you are acessing is not the one you think you are, when it contains that bit.

Comment: I thought the issue was that some code for the 8088/8086 exploited the fact that that addresses like 0xFFFF:0x0010 would wrap around to access physical memory at 0x00000, but on the 80286, even in emulation mode, such code would access physical memory at 0x100000.

Comment: @supercat: indeed that hack was used, which made matters worse (otherwise it would not have affected many people in real mode and intel might have said "then just use protected mode if you need some more memory")

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I wonder if there would have been any difficulty with wiring things so that RAM started at address 0x100000 but the first 640K of address space was aliased to that same address?  That would have reduced by 640K the amount of addressing space available for RAM in protected mode, but I don't know that people were pushing RAM over 14MB on the 286, were they?

Comment: @supercat: I doubt it. The 286 wasnt that popular (but not as unpopular as its smaller brother, the 186, which many people do not believe exists) and especially not for applications that needed much ram. It had quite some other misfeatures and only the ascend of the 386 made more ram really popular. But thats mostly speculation though.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: It's too bad Intel's engineers don't seem to have really understood what was good about the 8086 segment design (the fact that segment registers contain a scaled offset) and thus came up with a design with a very awkward granularity where objects had to be partitioned into different segments, but couldn't be given one segment each.  If Intel had included a programmable selector mask value and allowed code to interpret a segment as e.g. an 8-bit selector combined with an 8-bit scaled offset whose scaling factor could be controlled by the descriptor, that could have been...

Comment: ...a very nice architecture.  Real-mode code could have worked fairly well while still being able to access 16MB if it was configured to split the segments as 4+12 and the descriptor for segment e.g. 0xCnnn were configured to scale nnn by 4096 but all other segments were configured to scale by 16.